# Check if user exists with PRAW

Tags: python, search, reddit, praw

Is it possible to check if a specified user exists using PRAW, and if so what is the proper way to do so? I couldn't find any builtin functions that do this, so your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arnav's answer only works in old versions of PRAW ([prior to 2016](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package_info/change_log.html)). If you're starting a new project, you should use the newest version of PRAW. In that version, here's the code that works:

```
import praw
from prawcore.exceptions import NotFound

reddit = praw.Reddit(  # authentication goes here
)

def user_exists(name):
    try:
        reddit.redditor(name).id
    except NotFound:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @jarhill0, I'll make sure to add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function that does this, using `Reddit.get_redditor` and seeing if it finds a user:

```
def user_exists(username: str):
    try:
        r.get_redditor(username)
    except praw.exceptions.NotFound:
        return False
    return True
```

**EDIT**: Note that the function `get_redditor` only works in older versions of PRAW. Use [@jarhill0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807404/6525260)'s answer for the most up to date solution.